# White Screen Problem Google Play Store Console

Tags: google-play-services

i have created account on google playstore after click  verify button gets White Screen look like this.i couldn't verify it.how to solve the issues.
[image]

Comment: I'm faving this issue too - I removed a pay.google.com account and I'm wondering if it's related?